# Making sure a string doesn't contain any letters but specific ones with a regex if-statement

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to return False whenever the user enters the wrong input. To do this, I need to check the input and make sure it only contains specific letters. In this case I want to make sure their input only contains 'b', 'r', 'g', 'p', 'y', or 'o'. Theses letters represent colors in a "mastermind" game I am programming.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to properly use regex in python 2.7.

*How can I trigger an if-statement for any String that contains any characters other than these specific letters?*

**Example:**

```
# check for invalid letters
if re.search("^[brgpyo]", player_input_string):
    return False
```

Comment: is it case sensitive?

Comment: @Manaar I make the String lowercase beforehand

Comment: Hint: outside of a character class, `^` means start of string; within, it indicates negation (e.g. `^[brgpyo]` vs `[^brgpyo]`.

Comment: @orde thanks! It seems to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of a character class, `^` means start of string; within, `^` indicates negation of the elements within the character class.  For example:

```
import re

print(re.search("^[brgpyo]", "brgpyo"))
# <re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='b'>
print(re.search("^[brgpyo]", "argpyo"))
# None
print(re.search("[^brgpyo]", "brgpyo"))
# None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import string 
letters = set(string.ascii_letters) 
chars = ['b','r','g','p','y','o']
bad_chars = letters-set(chars) 
if bad_chars in player_input_string: 
      return False
```

Use the set here to be able to substract list from another list.

Answer (score 0):

result = re.search('[^brgpyo]*', player_input_string)
if result:
    return False

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use regex for this.

```
bad_chars = ['b','r','g','p','y','o']

if bad_chars in player_input_string:
     return False
```

Comment: I think those are supposed to be the good chars. If those are the only letters in the string, that string is fine

Comment: This does the exact opposite of what the questioner wants. He wants to ensure that *only* those characters are in the string.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without making a list of all the character *but* the ones I want?

Comment: Yes, check my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

If the player input string passes against the following regex, it meets your requirements:

```
(?i:[brgpyo].*)
```

This pattern is case insensitive, and only allows those letters to exist in the input string. The letters can occur in any order and with any frequency.

Comment: Python `re` does not support inline modifier groups.